# What does "EOFError: stream has been closed" mean?

Tags: python, eoferror

When running my code after a certain amount of time PyScripter opens another piece of code and gives the error message "EOFError: stream has been closed".

Here's the code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
from itertools import product, combinations
from numpy import *
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_aspect("equal")

ra_day = loadtxt("RA Days.txt")  
ra_minute = loadtxt("RA Minutes.txt")
ra_second = loadtxt("RA Seconds.txt")
ra = ra_day + (ra_minute/60) + (ra_second/3600)

dec_day = loadtxt("DEC Days.txt") 
dec_minute = loadtxt("DEC Minutes.txt")
dec_second = loadtxt("DEC Seconds.txt")
dec = dec_day + (dec_minute/60) + (dec_second/3600)

dist = loadtxt("Distance.txt")

for ra in range(754):
    for dec in range(754):
        for dist in range(754):
             x = math.cos(ra) * (dist * math.cos(dec))
             y = math.sin(ra) * (dist * math.cos(dec))
             z = dist * math.sin(dec)
             ax.scatter([x],[y],[z],color="k",s=100)

ax.scatter([0],[0],[0],color="b",s=100)

plt.show()
```

Please can someone help me with the error message. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

EOFerror is end of file error; it could be thrown if one of your files is empty, or if you try to read more lines than are in the file.